# Determine amount of traffic flowing on specific route

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to determine amount of traffic flowing on specific route (in percentage or in any other unit)?
As google live traffic is represented by four different colors which depends upon traffic conditions, so what percentage of traffic is represented by red and green color?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API doesn't expose much quantitative traffic information about roads and routes.  You might have some luck looking at the `duration_in_traffic` response field from the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro).  This field returns the time a route takes, based on the `traffic_model` you've specified.